# mod_wsgi-express: error: Invalid command was specified

Tags: apache, python-2.7

I am trying to run wsgi application (`hello.wsgi`) on `localhost` through `apache24` with `mod_wsgi` module but it shows this:

```
cd c:/apache24/bin
mod_wsgi-express start-server hello.wsgi
```

> ```
> Usage: mod_wsgi-express command [params]
>
> Commands:
>     module-config
>     module-location
>
> mod_wsgi-express: error: Invalid command was specified.
> ```

Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

On Windows the `start-server` command is not available. Using `pip install mod_wsgi` on Windows is only for getting the `mod_wsgi` module compiled. Once you have it compiled, run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

Copy the output from that into your Apache configuration file to have it load the `mod_wsgi` module. Then configure Apache manually to host your specific WSGI application.

See section "Connecting into Apache installation" in:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

for more details about the `module-config` command.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me..!!

Comment: C:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd -k restart
httpd: Syntax error on line 182 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgiNone.pyd into server: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: You are using Python 2.7. The results for it are wrong for some people. Haven't been able to get anyone to help me enough to work out change required to code. Tell me what files are in the directory ``c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/``. Specifically names of files starting with ``mod_wsgi``. The generated extension is wrong so need to work out what extension file was given.

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin>httpd -k restart
httpd: Syntax error on line 197 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.pyd into server: The specified module could not be found.